# How to direct a Domain to a subfolder on the server it points to in apache htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I have a web server with several Domains pointing to it. I want one domain lets name it www.example.com to go into the folder /example in my Doc Root (e.g. /var/www/example). I do this using this .htaccess code in my Doc Root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ example [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now typing in the domain in the browser gets me to the correct location but instead of seeing www.example.com or example.com in the url bar of my browser I see [IP-Address]/example (e.g. 1.2.3.4/example). Of course I want the domain name www.example.com to show up and if I surf to a specific file e.g. /example/folder/index.php I want (www.)example.com/folder/index.php to show up.

I have tried some of the proposed fixes from other stack overflow questions regarding redirect to subfolder but all of them seem to elicit the above unwanted behaviour. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!band/).*$ /band/$0 [L,NC]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing.

`(?!band/)` is a negative lookahead to prevent redirect when request already starts with `/band/`.

Comment: Hello anubhava, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the problem still persists. I still have an address of form IP-Address/example after your change. Maybee something with my apache config is wrong.

Comment: I have removed `R=301` flag. Try updated rules in a new browser or command line curl